# Add a field to a form, php not working anymore

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Need some help regarding this, been at this problem for quite some time now but can´t seem to solve it, bit of a noob :/

This code works fine as a contact form but I want to add a phone number field to it.

This is what I have working:

---

HTML

```
        <form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="#">
            <p class="contact-name">
                <input id="contact_name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" value="" name="name" />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-email">
                <input id="contact_email" type="text" placeholder="Your e-Mail" value="" name="email" />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-message">
                <textarea id="contact_message" placeholder="Your message" name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p class="contact-submit">
                <a id="contact-submit" class="submit" href="#">Send</a>
            </p>

            <div id="response">

            </div>
        </form>
```

---

contact.php

---

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$admin_email = 'name@email.org'; // Your Email
$message_min_length = 5; // Min Message Length


class Contact_Form{
  function __construct($details, $email_admin, $message_min_length){

    $this->name = stripslashes($details['name']);
    $this->email = trim($details['email']);
    $this->subject = 'Contact Website'; // Subject 
    $this->message = stripslashes($details['message']);

    $this->email_admin = $email_admin;
    $this->message_min_length = $message_min_length;

    $this->response_status = 1;
    $this->response_html = '';
  }


  private function validateEmail(){
    $regex = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i';

    if($this->email == '') { 
      return false;
    } else {
      $string = preg_replace($regex, '', $this->email);
    }

    return empty($string) ? true : false;
  }


  private function validateFields(){
    // Check name
    if(!$this->name)
    {
      $this->response_html .= '<p>Name field is required</p>';
      $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check email
    if(!$this->email)
    {
      $this->response_html .= '<p>e-Mail field is required</p>';
      $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check valid email
    if($this->email && !$this->validateEmail())
    {
      $this->response_html .= '<p>e-Mail field is required</p>';
      $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check message length
    if(!$this->message || strlen($this->message) < $this->message_min_length)
    {
      $this->response_html .= '<p>Message is required with a minimum of '.$this->message_min_length.' characters</p>';
      $this->response_status = 0;
    }
  }


  private function sendEmail(){
    $mail = mail($this->email_admin, $this->subject, $this->message,
       "From: ".$this->name." <".$this->email.">\r\n"
      ."Reply-To: ".$this->email."\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

    if($mail)
    {
      $this->response_status = 1;
      $this->response_html = '<p>Thanks, message is sent!</p>';
    }
  }


  function sendRequest(){
    $this->validateFields();
    if($this->response_status)
    {
      $this->sendEmail();
    }

    $response = array();
    $response['status'] = $this->response_status;   
    $response['html'] = $this->response_html;

    echo json_encode($response);
  }
}


$contact_form = new Contact_Form($_POST, $admin_email, $message_min_length);
$contact_form->sendRequest();

?>
```

---

Now I tried the following:

---

HTML

```
        <form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="#">
            <p class="contact-name">
                <input id="contact_name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" value="" name="name" />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-email">
                <input id="contact_email" type="text" placeholder="Your e-Mail" value="" name="email" />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-phone">
                <input id="contact_phone" type="text" placeholder="Uw telefoonnummer" value="" name="phone" />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-message">
                <textarea id="contact_message" placeholder="Your message" name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p class="contact-submit">
                <a id="contact-submit" class="submit" href="#">Send</a>
            </p>

            <div id="response">

            </div>
        </form>
```

---

contact.php

---

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$admin_email = 'name@email.org'; // Your Email
$message_min_length = 5; // Min Message Length


class Contact_Form{
  function __construct($details, $email_admin, $message_min_length){

    $this->name = stripslashes($details['name']);
    $this->email = trim($details['email']);
    $this->phone = trim($details['phone']);
    $this->subject = 'Contact Website'; // Subject 
    $this->message = stripslashes($details['phone';'message']);

    $this->email_admin = $email_admin;
    $this->message_min_length = $message_min_length;

    $this->response_status = 1;
    $this->response_html = '';
  }


  private function validateEmail(){
    $regex = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i';

    if($this->email == '') { 
      return false;
    } else {
      $string = preg_replace($regex, '', $this->email);
    }

    return empty($string) ? true : false;
  }


  private function validateFields(){
    // Check name
    if(!$this->name)
    {
      $this->response_html .= '<p>Name field is required</p>';
      $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check email
    if(!$this->email)
    {
      $this->response_html .= '<p>e-Mail field is required</p>';
      $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check phone
    if(!$this->phone)
    {
      $this->response_html .= '<p>Phone field is required</p>';
      $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check valid email
    if($this->email && !$this->validateEmail())
    {
      $this->response_html .= '<p>e-Mail field is required</p>';
      $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check message length
    if(!$this->message || strlen($this->message) < $this->message_min_length)
    {
      $this->response_html .= '<p>Message is required with a minimum of '.$this->message_min_length.' characters</p>';
      $this->response_status = 0;
    }
  }


  private function sendEmail(){
    $mail = mail($this->email_admin, $this->subject, $this->message, $this->phone,
       "From: ".$this->name." <".$this->email.">\r\n"
      ."Reply-To: ".$this->email."\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

    if($mail)
    {
      $this->response_status = 1;
      $this->response_html = '<p>Thanks, message is sent!</p>';
    }
  }


  function sendRequest(){
    $this->validateFields();
    if($this->response_status)
    {
      $this->sendEmail();
    }

    $response = array();
    $response['status'] = $this->response_status;   
    $response['html'] = $this->response_html;

    echo json_encode($response);
  }
}


$contact_form = new Contact_Form($_POST, $admin_email, $message_min_length);
$contact_form->sendRequest();

?>
```

---

And various other things, also have tried this:

```
$this->message = stripslashes($details['phone','message']);
```

but no luck

This:

```
$this->message = stripslashes($details['phone,message']);
```

no luck either

Comment: Are you using any javascript to submit the form?

Comment: Are you trying to combine number in front of message?

Comment: If the phone number appears in the first or last line in the message, so it get's sent in the message body

Comment: By the looks of `<a id="contact-submit" class="submit" href="#">Send</a>`, yeah, I tend to think that you are using JS, but you failed to show us that and I feel the problem is in there, and not in what you posted. PHP cannot process that as pure PHP, it would need JS to make it work.

Comment: And if not that ^ then the semi-colon in this `stripslashes($details['phone';'message']);` ends the statement. It's also wrong for a few reasons.

Comment: I'd start by enabling error reporting and looking at your console; should this be JS related.

Comment: You're not helping here by not responding to comments. Asking for help means that you are asking us to respond and we have but you have not updated your question to contain the missing code. Voting as unclear. The more you wait, the more time it takes, remember that. Now you have just the one person trying to do their best and still... you say it doesn't work. You are wasting their time, yours and ours.

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] please? The code in your question is a little verbose.

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/).

Answer (score -2):

## PHP fix

Try

```
$this->message = stripslashes($details['phone'] . $details['message']);
```

Or probably even better:

```
$this->message = stripslashes($details['message']. ' - Phone: ' . $details['phone']);
```

You could read up on [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [strings concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) to learn how this works.

## HTML fix

Your form doesn't link to contact.php anywhere. Change your form tag to

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Hi JoerT, just tried this, the form resets after hitting submit, no message that it is sent and doesn't send e-mail

Comment: No, thanks for the great effort, but unfortunately doesn't work, same thing, the form resets after hitting submit, no message that it is sent and doesn't send e-mail

Comment: I just tried out your PHP code, and it seems to be alright. Running it by itself  (without your form) outputs `{"status":1,"html":"<p>Thanks, message is sent!<\/p>"}`. I'm guessing the problem is in your form itself. Have you tried turning on the developer console and checking 'preserve log'?

Comment: Your form doesn't refer to contact.php. I updated my answer with a fix for that too.